# Binarization of white and black texts in images

Tags: image-processing

Many of the document image binarization algorithms assume the black texts are on a white background or vice versa. My question is what I can do if white and black texts coexist in one document image. Any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: you play with the white/black threshold if there is enough contrast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detect the black regions and invert them.

Comment: This is one solution, but then another problem rises. How could you tell which black region deserve another round of binarization？ Consider the situation where the text and the illustration picture are mixed.

Comment: Indeed, that situation was not described in the question. I always try the easy things first.